# Set product attribute value in magento errors

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm writing an importer that creates new attribute (which works) and now I want to set different attribute values for different products, without using attribute sets. A method that seems to work for a lot of people seems to be the following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes([$id], ['color'=>'red'], self::STORE_ID);
```

Sadly this errors for me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'where clause'' in /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /vagrant/htdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#6 /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#7 /vagrant/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.p in /vagrant/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Is there a better method or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In order to save attribute values for product, you have to load product object first then set attribute values.. See the example below:

```
$id = 102; // Your product id    
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id);
        $product->setStatus(1);  
        $product->setColor("red");
        $product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have learned a very good and performant way is to work with the Resource model:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setId($productId);
$product->setStoreId($storeId);
$product->setColor('red');

// or
// $product->setDataUsingMethod('color', 'red')

$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
$resource->saveAttribute($product, 'color');
```

Comment: Where is the attribute value?

Comment: The attribute value is set on the Model class in $product. You hand the Model class and the attribute code to $resource->saveAttribute.

Comment: sorry, what i meant to say was: Where can I see the product value in the backend? The 'Manage Products' session doesn't show me product attributes

Comment: Oh I'm not sure if that is working. I have never tried without attribute sets. I would guess your product needs an attribute set for the backend fields to show. Asked a colleague, he also says so.